# Web pack build in laravel : Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery error

Tags: php, jquery, webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

Here is my script for webpack build with laravel mix

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');    
mix.js([
        'public/admin/js/jquery.js',
        'public/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    ],'production/js/final.js');
```

But when i include `final.js` i got the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

I've installed the jquery with `npm install jquery --save` but still i got above error

Comment: You're mixing a dependent stuff into one entry. The order may wrong or it just don't work either. Laravel has an example on how to bootstrap them by default.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your comment??

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: I didn't get how this will relate to my problem??

Answer (score 1):

i've had this issue quite a while ago. In my case after some googling i came to the conclusion that i forgot to install the `bootstrap-sass-loader` so incase that you are using the `bootstrap-sass` package do make sure you've installed the loader aswell. You can do this by running the following command:

```
$ npm install bootstrap-sass-loader --save
```

If this isn't the case try to take a look at [this](https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial) it isn't a tutorial for your problem exactly but it does show some simulair tutorials and answers.

Hope it helps!

Comment: wait Let me try it

Comment: @Jabaa Then you should take a look at the link i've put in my answer maybe that gives the solution to your problem

Comment: Thats ROR tutorial here i am using laravel

Comment: yes iknow @Jabaa it isn't a laravel tutorial but it does have simulair workflow's. Besides the link was and is a suggestion. Not an answer